# Is it possible to write function and procedure within single program in PL/SQL without using packages?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to calculate LCM using GCF but somehow i'm getting error saying "no function with name LCM exists in the scope". What can i do about this?. I think this error is because i'm writing procedure and function together..

```
create or replace FUNCTION gcf (
    x   IN INTEGER,
    y   IN INTEGER
) RETURN INTEGER IS
    res   INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF ( y = 0 ) OR MOD(y,x) = 0 THEN
        RETURN x;
    ELSIF ( x = 0 ) THEN
        RETURN y;
    ELSIF ( x < y ) THEN
        res := gcf(y,x);
    ELSE
        res := gcf(y,MOD(x,y) );
    END IF;

    RETURN res;
END;
/
create or replace PROCEDURE lcm (
    num1     IN INTEGER,
    num2     IN INTEGER,
    answer   OUT INTEGER
) IS

BEGIN
    IF num1 = 0 AND num2 = 0 THEN
        answer := 0;
    ELSE
        answer := abs(num1 * num2) / gcf(num1,num2);
    END IF;
END lcm;
/
DECLARE
c integer;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(8, 12)-> ' || lcm(8, 12,c) );
    dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(38,150)-> ' || lcm(38,150,c) );
    dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(16,50)-> ' || lcm(16,60,c) );
    dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(16,60)-> ' || lcm(16,60,c) );
     dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(48,99)-> ' || lcm(48,99,c) );
END;
/
```

Comment: By the way, that isn't a "single program". You are creating two stored program units and then using them in an anonymous block. Also, when it says no **function** "LCM" exists, it's right. LCM is a procedure, not a function.

Comment: Sure..:). I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a PL/SQL procedure like a function. You must simply run it without being part of any other expression, which will set the value of the out parameter c.

```
DECLARE
c integer;

BEGIN
 lcm(8, 12,c);
    dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(8, 12)-> '  || c);

 lcm(38,150,c);
    dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(38,150)->' || c);

 lcm(16,60,c);
    dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(16,50)-> '  || c);

 lcm(16,60,c);
    dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(16,60)-> '  || c);

 lcm(48,99,c);

     dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(48,99)-> ' || c );
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the procedure and function inside the procedure as follows:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE lcm (
    num1     IN INTEGER,
    num2     IN INTEGER,
    answer   OUT INTEGER
) IS
FUNCTION gcf (
    x   IN INTEGER,
    y   IN INTEGER
) RETURN INTEGER IS
    res   INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF ( y = 0 ) OR MOD(y,x) = 0 THEN
        RETURN x;
    ELSIF ( x = 0 ) THEN
        RETURN y;
    ELSIF ( x < y ) THEN
        res := gcf(y,x);
    ELSE
        res := gcf(y,MOD(x,y) );
    END IF;

    RETURN res;
END;
BEGIN
    IF num1 = 0 AND num2 = 0 THEN
        answer := 0;
    ELSE
        answer := abs(num1 * num2) / gcf(num1,num2);
    END IF;
END lcm;
/
```

Then call it:

```
DECLARE
   c   INTEGER;
BEGIN
   lcm (8, 12, c);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' LCM(8, 12)-> ' || c);
   lcm (38, 150, c);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' LCM(38,150)-> ' || c);
   lcm (16, 60, c);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' LCM(16,50)-> ' || c);
   lcm (16, 60, c);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' LCM(16,60)-> ' || c);
   lcm (48, 99, c);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' LCM(48,99)-> ' || c);
END;
```

Comment: You are Awesome..:) .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Lowest Common Multiple should be a function (since it returns a single value):

```
CREATE FUNCTION lcm (
    num1     IN INTEGER,
    num2     IN INTEGER,
) RETURN INTEGER DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  IF num1 = 0 AND num2 = 0 THEN
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
  RETURN abs(num1 * num2) / gcf(num1,num2);
END lcm;
/
```

Then you can use the code:

```
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(8, 12)-> ' || lcm(8, 12) );
  dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(38,150)-> ' || lcm(38,150) );
  dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(16,50)-> ' || lcm(16,60) );
  dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(16,60)-> ' || lcm(16,60) );
  dbms_output.put_line(' LCM(48,99)-> ' || lcm(48,99) );
END;
/
```